# append a string to a column

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, varchar

I have a column of numbers and want to populate another column with these numbers plus the additional text " millions". So "20" would become "20 million". How do I add this?

I have tried running the SQL queries

```
UPDATE numbers
SET values_new=values + ' millions'
```

and

```
UPDATE numbers
SET values_new=values + cast (' millions' as nvarchar(max))
```

but an error occurs with both. What else could I try?

Comment: what is the datatype on the column you are trying to update?  what is the error message?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near....

Comment: The data type was text but i changed it to varchar to see if it would make a difference but the error message is the same each time

Comment: looks like you will need to convert the values field, if it is a number. please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `values` to a string instead:

```
SET values_new = cast(values as nvarchar(20)) + ' millions'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column value is a numeric type, you have to cast it, not the text you are appending:

```
UPDATE numbers 
SET values_new=cast(values as varchar(5)) + ' millions'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the column is a `varchar` then you will do the following:

```
UPDATE numbers
SET values_new= cast(values as varchar(50)) + ' millions'
```